# Asp.Net Core Project Published

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, web-hosting

How to published or hosting my Asp.net Core MVC Project To asphostportal.com or any other domain website.
Is it Azure Mandatory for any asp.net core project.
I already published many webform project on BigRock but .net core project is little bit complicated.

Comment: You may refer to https://windowswebhostingreview.com/how-to-publish-asp-net-5-on-asphostportal-hosting/. I follow this tutorial and it is working without any issue.

Comment: on website said its support .Net 5.0.2 and my project .Net version is only 5.0. So , will I facing any problem when published

Comment: @MarkSpencer which website you recommended to published any .Net core project?

Comment: Asphostportal, I can publish .net core successfully on their server.

Comment: @MarkSpencer is it Migration automatically  after published

Comment: What do you mean automatically? When you signed up with them, they will give you direction how to upload your files to their server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that the method is same. You just need to publish your files on their root folder and then configure your application.

Below is one of the link where you can find .net core running on GoDaddy's server

https://www.hanselman.com/blog/running-aspnet-core-on-godaddys-cheapest-shared-linux-hosting-dont-try-this-at-home

https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/how-to-deploy-net-core-application-on-linux/

Comment: which website you recommended to published any .Net core project?